# Dragonfly installation issues with Windows speech recognition

Tags: installation, python-dragonfly

I want to do speech recognition using Dragonfly with Windows Speech Recognition on windows 10 but the issue is it always displays the errors.I am stuck to in since days. This is all I have been trying to do:

1. First I downloaded python 2.7.6.msi, then installed pywin32-218.win32-py2.7.exe, then wxPython2.8-win32-ansi-2.8.12.1-py27.exe.
2. Then I added its path to system variables
3. Then I downloaded dragonfly 0.6.5 from 2 links so that either works because first one didnt work but unfortunately it didn't too.As I try running its setup.py file through command line, it says:

   > error: could not create 'dragonfly.egg-info': Access is denied

   As I try running its dfly loader file on IDLE 3.5 (since I have that installed, hope that's not an issue), it says:

   ```
   invalid syntax on this first line;

     **except Exception, e**:
           self._log.error("%s: Error loading module: %s" % (self, e))
           self._loaded = False
           return
   ```

   while in other programs, it says no module named 'win32gui'. I also tried working on different Python versions but no progress.

Comment: Questions are _much_ easier to read when they have some basic Markdown applied. When you get chance, please do have a play with the formatting tools - it reduces the workload for editors here, thanks.

Comment: Yes  Ure right!Appologies!

Comment: @halfer any idea?

Comment: No, sorry; I'm just an editor here. It sounds like file permission issues - what is the full path it is trying to write `dragonfly.egg-info` to? Maybe if it is installing something, and you trust it, run this thing as Administrator?

Comment: Also, could you be trying to run Python 3 code on Python 2? The syntax error makes me wonder if that could be worth looking into - docs?

Comment: I have tried that too but i doubt if there is some placement of some files or libraries that needs to be in python folder may be or dragonfly?still thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using lib2to3 to convert the dragonfly source codes, this will solve the latter problem, i.e. except Exception, e. Python3 code should render as except Exception as e